# Storing variables from AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I gain access to variables that come from a ajax request that is returned from a function? I can console.out the variable, but I can't seem to store it outside the scope.

How it looks like:

1. In the html:

   function my_ajax() {

   ```
   var stuff = 'stuff';
   return $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "file.php",
       data: {"something": "wrong"}
   }); /* end ajax */
   ```

   } /* end my_ajax() */

...then in the js-file:

```
my_ajax().then(function(response){
        var elements = jQuery.parseJSON(response);              
        var one = elements.one;
        var two = elements.two;

//now say that I need to use 'one' outside this function. I try this:

    stuff(elements);

    });
```

//this works

```
function stuff(el) {
var something = el.one;
console.log(something);
}
```

//this doesn't work

```
function stuff(el) {
var something = el.one;
return something;
}
```

//this works

```
var try_obj = {
    please_work: function(el) {
        var something = el.one;
        console.log(something);
    }
};
```

So how do I store variables from ajax of this nature so that I can reuse them on the html-page or in the js-file? I need to send them back with another ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the values in a variable that exists outside of the calling function, you need declare it outside of the function initially.

So, if you want to have the 'something' value available anywhere on the page, you would do something like:

```
my_ajax().then(function(response){
    var elements = jQuery.parseJSON(response);              
    var one = elements.one;
    var two = elements.two;

    savestuff(elements);

});

//declaring this outside of any function makes it available to all
var something = "";

//save to the previously declared 'something' variable
function savestuff(el) {
    something = el.one;  /* no 'var' so JS knows to look in page / global scope  */
    showstuff();
}

//access the value from any function on the page freely
function showstuff(){
    alert(something);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works (interesting method), but if I don't call showstuff() in savestuff(), and I try to console.out 'something', I'll get an undefined. Each time I want to reuse the variable, I have to call the function in question. I don't suppose there's a way to call .window instead of a function, so that the variable can work independently?

Comment: yes, in savestuff() you can use window.something = el.one;

Answer (score 4):

You are using Ajax incorrectly. The idea is not to have it return anything, but instead hand off the data to something called a callback function, which handles the data (for example, your second AJAX call).

```
function handleData( responseData ) {

    // Do what you want with the data
    console.log(responseData);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "hi.php",
    ...
    success: function ( data, status, XHR ) {
        handleData(data);
    }
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I used return because it worked for my particular problem (saw the solution on stack).

Comment: Looks that it won't work for me here, unless I reconstruct all my code. Still, a thumbs up for making me more aware of that method. thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an object like `try_obj` accessible globally then it's as simple as:

```js
my_ajax().then(function(response){
    var elements = jQuery.parseJSON(response);              
    var one = elements.one;
    var two = elements.two;

//now say that I need to use 'one' outside this function. I try this:

try_obj.ajaxStore = elements;

});
```

Then just call `try_obj.ajaxStore` from wherever you need to.

Here is a alternative. You could set a global variable:

```js
my_ajax().then(function(response){
    var elements = jQuery.parseJSON(response);              
    var one = elements.one;
    var two = elements.two;

//now say that I need to use 'one' outside this function. I try this:

window.ajaxStore = elements;

});
```

Then `ajaxStore` can be used anywhere. Usually you want to avoid using global variables, however.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside of the AJAX call, assign the value to the variable on the AJAX return, like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    var elements = {};
    var promise = $.ajax({
       //ajax stuff
    }).success(function(response) {
       elements = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    });
    promise.always(console.log(elements));
}
```

Comment: `elements` is always going to be an empty object in that `console.log`

Comment: you're right.  i was thinking async.  i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you show define variable outside of my_ajax promise.

```
var elements;

my_ajax().then(function(response){
   elements = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
   ...
}

console.log(elements);
```